# Help building a SQL query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot

Given the following tables, how might I build a SQL query that includes a list of all the items from the "items" table, and a column for each color from the "colors" table that, for each item listed, indicates what colors the item has a relationship with.

If that is unclear at all, please let me know what additional information will help clarify. The table information and desired SQL result are below:

**items table:**

```
id | item_name
1  | 'item 1'
2  | 'item 2'
3  | 'item 3'
```

**colors table:**

```
id | color_name
1  | 'red'
2  | 'blue'
3  | 'green'
```

**item_color table:**

```
item_id | color_id
1       | 1
1       | 3
2       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 2
```

**Desired SQL query result:**

```
item_name | red | blue | green
'item 1'  |  1  | null |   1
'item 2'  | null|   1  |   1
'item 3'  | null|   1  | null
```

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT item_name,
       MAX(red) 'red',
       MAX(blue) 'blue',
       MAX(green) 'green'
  FROM (SELECT t.item_name,
         CASE
           WHEN c.color_name = 'red' THEN
             1
           ELSE
             NULL
         END 'red',
         CASE
           WHEN c.color_name = 'blue' THEN
             1
           ELSE
             NULL
         END 'blue',
         CASE
           WHEN c.color_name = 'green' THEN
             1
           ELSE
             NULL
         END 'green'       
    FROM ITEMS t
    JOIN ITEM_COLOR ic ON ic.item_id = t.item_id
    JOIN COLORS c ON c.id = ic.color_id)
GROUP BY item_name
```

Change MAX to COUNT if you want the total # of red/blue/green associated to an item.

Alternate using Subquery Factoring:

```
WITH icolors AS (
   SELECT t.item_name,
          CASE
           WHEN c.color_name = 'red' THEN
             1
           ELSE
             NULL
         END 'red',
     CASE
       WHEN c.color_name = 'blue' THEN
         1
       ELSE
         NULL
     END 'blue',
     CASE
       WHEN c.color_name = 'green' THEN
         1
       ELSE
             NULL
     END 'green'       
    FROM ITEMS t
    JOIN ITEM_COLOR ic ON ic.item_id = t.item_id
    JOIN COLORS c ON c.id = ic.color_id)
  SELECT t.item_name,
         MAX(t.red) 'red',
         MAX(t.blue) 'blue',
         MAX(t.green) 'green'
    FROM icolors t
GROUP BY t.item_name
```

Comment: @rexem: How would I go about grouping the results such that each item_name appears only once and each color "indicator" appears in that same row? (see the desired output in my question as an example)

Comment: @rexem: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. This produces what I was hoping for.

I did have to remove the parentheses around the string after each "END" and after each "MAX()", as I was getting errors in TOAD. Any idea as to why?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Colin: you mean single quotes.  Dunno why TOAD has a problem with that syntax for column aliasing - Management Studio and PL/SQL Developer don't.

Comment: @rexem: I meant single quotes - sorry about that. Strange that TOAD has a problem with that syntax. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on oracle 11g?

This seems to be an ideal use for the new [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/oracle-database-11g-top-features/11g-pivot.html) feature in 11g

Comment: Yes, Chi - I'm on Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Chi: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Chi: Not specific to the question.

Comment: @Chi: Thanks a lot for the link. I was not aware of the feature!

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the possible colours in advance, you can do it messily but effectively.
If you don't know all the possible colours in advance, it is very much harder - you have to run some queries to find out which columns will appear in the result table, and then craft the SQL to create those columns (dynamic SQL).

So, let's assume you know the columns in the result table:

```
SELECT i.item_name, r.red, b.blue, g.green
  FROM items i
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT item_name, COUNT(*) AS red
          FROM item_color
         WHERE color_id = 1
         GROUP BY item_name) AS r
       ON i.item_name = r.item_name
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT item_name, COUNT(*) AS green
          FROM item_color
         WHERE color_id = 3
         GROUP BY item_name) AS g
       ON i.item_name = g.item_name
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT item_name, COUNT(*) AS blue
          FROM item_color
         WHERE color_id = 2
         GROUP BY item_name) AS b
       ON i.item_name = b.item_name
```

Note that in this formulation, I've used the data from the *colours* table in building the query.  And alternative form would build the sub-queries as (inner) joins to the colours table, using the colour name instead of the code in the WHERE clauses.

Comment: If you only need existence tests, not counts, then @rexem has a simpler and effective solution - but again, requires you to know the full set of colours to build the query.

Comment: that's where the pivot command comes in, it lets you do the query without knowing all the possible colors in advance and without dynamically crafting sql

Comment: @Chi: yes, the PIVOT command (clause in SELECT) at least partly deals with that.  The example shown at the referenced URL indicates a manually generated list of the interested columns - `PIVOT (...for colour in ('red', 'green', 'blue')...)`; however, the full manual shows that you can have a sub-query for the IN list...

Answer (score 1):

```
create table item (id number not null, item_name varchar2(200) not null);
create table color (id number not null, color_name varchar2(200) not null);
create table item_color (item_id number not null, color_id number not null);

insert into item values (1, 'item 1');
insert into item values (2, 'item 2');
insert into item values (3, 'item 3');


insert into color values (1, 'red');
insert into color values (2, 'blue');
insert into color values (3, 'green');

insert into item_color values (1, 1);
insert into item_color values (1, 3);
insert into item_color values (2, 2);
insert into item_color values (2, 3);
insert into item_color values (3, 2);

commit;
```

then select:

```
select * from
(
select
  i.item_name
  , c.color_name
from
  item i
  , color c
  , item_color ic
where
  ic.item_id = i.id
  and ic.color_id = c.id
) pivot (
  count(color_name) cnt
  for color_name in ('red', 'blue', 'green')
);
```

gives:

```
item 1    1    0    1
item 2    0    1    1
item 3    0    1    0
```

in case you don't know the list of colors beforehand you can select the color table first and then build the pivot select dynamically (a subselect like `for color_name in (select color_name from color)` is not possible) or alternatively you can use `pivot xml` and postprocess the result:

```
select * from
(
select
  i.item_name
  , c.color_name
from
  item i
  , color c
  , item_color ic
where
  ic.item_id = i.id
  and ic.color_id = c.id
) pivot xml (
  count(color_name) cnt
  for color_name in (any)
)
```

gives:

```
item 1  <PivotSet><item><column name = "COLOR_NAME">green</column><column name = "CNT">1</column></item><item><column name = "COLOR_NAME">red</column><column name = "CNT">1</column></item></PivotSet>
item 2  <PivotSet><item><column name = "COLOR_NAME">blue</column><column name = "CNT">1</column></item><item><column name = "COLOR_NAME">green</column><column name = "CNT">1</column></item></PivotSet>
item 3  <PivotSet><item><column name = "COLOR_NAME">blue</column><column name = "CNT">1</column></item></PivotSet>
```